# JSF Required Message being displayed twice

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Here is the senorio and codes.  JSF Required Message being displayed twice. how can i solve?

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg['text.surdurulebilir']} :"/>
                            <p:rating value="#{appraisalBean.newAppraisal.ratingSustainability}" stars="10"
                                      readonly="#{sessionBean.loggedUser.fullName == 'Admin' or sessionBean.loggedUser.fullName == 'Moderator'}"
                                      required="true" requiredMessage="Sürdürülebilirlik Değerlendirilme Alanı Boş Bırakılamaz."  id="star5"/>
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code that displays these messages! Please, always create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

please check your `p:messages` tag and both `showDetails` and `showSummary` attribute are set to true. That's why two messages are displaying one for *summery* and another for *detail*. One more doubt I have you may be adding messages from java file as well